# Linux mint on pendrive after shutting down a system goes back to default mode

Tags: linux, usb, usb-flash-drive, linux-mint

I have a problem that after shutting down Linux mint (which I have installed od pendrive) all go back to default setting such as sensitivity of mouse or system colors. Also I lost all aplications I have installed (vs code and chrome). Whenever I restart, I lose all my changes to system. When I'm closing I also get this messgae "Please remove the installation medium, then press enter". I used rufus to move linux on my pendrive (pendrive is Kingstone DataTraveler 3.0 64GB).

I've checked if I haven't by an accident installing aplications on my regular hardrive with windows, but I'm 100% positive that it isn't there, so usb-drive for some reason is deleting all my changes and files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Create a persistent USB install. When creating the live USB via Rufus, there is an option for **Persistent partition size**. Make sure you allocate enough space, too.
2. You might want to recreate the live USB again, and make sure that you're selecting the persistent option.
3. Check if "**Read-Only**" mode is active. Some live USB's might boot into a read-only mode to preserve the original install.
4. If possible, see if this happens with a different USB Drive